# is there a more efficient way than this method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, refactoring

The Job is to decompress a string.
**For example:**

```
if a string is 'a3b4c2' then decompress it as 'aaabbbbcc'.
```

the previous code i tried is

```
list1 = [i for i in a]
listNum = list(map(int,list(filter(lambda x:x.isdigit(),list1))))
listChar = list(filter(lambda x: not x.isdigit(),list1))
b = ''
for i in range(len(listNum)):
    b += listChar[i]*listNum[i]
print(b)
```

I think it is a pretty simple problem, but my code seems clumsy, is there any other method to do it?.

Comment: If you're looking for code review, you should post to [codereview.se] instead. Also, you're going through your list _three full times_ - you could do the same thing with just one loop

Comment: not reviewing but asking for any other approach or method to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

b = ''.join(c * int(n) for c, n in re.findall(r'(\w)(\d+)', a))
```

The regex will match each letter with the following number (accommodating multi-digit numbers) and return them in groups:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\w)(\d+)', a)
[('a', '3'), ('b', '4'), ('c', '2')]
```

Then you just need to iterate over them…

```
for c, n in ...
# c = 'a'
# n = '3'
# ...
```

…and multiply them…

```
c * int(n)
```

…and simply do that in a generator expression…

```
c * int(n) for c, n in re.findall(r'(\w)(\d+)', a)
```

…and `''.join` all the resulting small strings together.

For fun, here's a version that even allows standalone letters without numbers:

```
a = 'a3bc4d2e'
b = ''.join(c * int(n or 1) for c, n in re.findall(r'(\w)(\d+)?', a))
# aaabccccdde
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another way, `zip` + `splicing`,

```
>>> value = 'a3b4c2'
>>> 
>>> "".join(x*int(y) for x, y in zip(value[0::2], value[1::2]))
'aaabbbbcc'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension for a one line solution:

```
input='a3b4c2'
result=''.join(input[i] * int(input[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(input),2))
```

Output:

```
>>> result
aaabbbbcc
```

- The * operator can be used to multiply an integer with a character.
- The join method is called to join the list of the substrings to the full string.

Comment: is there a way to do it in inplace?

Comment: what do you mean by inplace?

Comment: i am not sure but the platform i am practicing says inplace(without using extra space)

Comment: @PurushothamanU Since you're talking about strings, and strings are immutable in Python, that's not possible. You *at least* need a copy of the string…

Comment: Okay, Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You might do it using regular expressions (`re` module), using grouping and function as 2nd [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) argument following way

```
import re
a = 'a3b4c2'
def decompress(x):
    return x.group(1)*int(x.group(2))
output = re.sub(r'(\D)(\d+)', decompress, a)
print(output)  # aaabbbbcc
```

Explanation I am looking in string for single non-digit (`\D`) followed by one or more digits (`\d+`). For every match first is put into 1st group and latter into 2nd group, hence brackets in pattern. Then every match is replaced by content of 1st group (which is string) times *value* of content of 2nd group. Note that I used `int` to get that value as attempt of direct multiplying would fail (you can not multiply string by string).

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the `string` pairwise using `zip`, to get the char `c` and int `n` as separate elements and then replicate the char `c` for `n` times

```
>>> str = 'a3b4c2'
>>> s = iter(str)
>>> ''.join(c*int(n) for c,n in zip(s, s))
'aaabbbbcc'
```